# PayPal API charging card but returning error

Tags: paypal

Please excuse me if this is a newbie question but I have never worked with any sort of credit card API before and I am, well, pretty much a newbie...

I have a script with "PayPal integrated" heh, and its not working.
When I run a card on the PayPal Sandbox, the transaction seems to go through, my sandbox account gets credited the amount but the script returns this error:

```
TIMESTAMP:  2011-04-25T14:03:42Z
CORRELATIONID:  5e727288789fb
ACK:  SuccessWithWarning
L_LONGMESSAGE0:  This transaction has been completed, but the total of items in the cart did not match the total of all items.
AMT:  25.00
CURRENCYCODE:  EUR
AVSCODE:  X
TRANSACTIONID:  4MM79765A4836914N
```

I understand the error message, but I am not sure where to begin looking in order to try and rectify it.
Sorry if this question is blurry, I am pretty lost and hoping that someone could just help get me pointed in the right direction here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like this is something you would ask the PayPal technical support forums, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: True, I am awaiting a response on their forums. My experience with the users here at Stack Overflow has just been so impressive that I thought I would give it a shot here. I was hoping that it might be a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

"In your request string you may have use &L_COST0=18.00& for amount".
which may create problem for transaction, The variable for line item is L_AMTn so in this case it should be &L_AMT0=18.00&.

Just try this if needed. otherwise send the request string you had pass for more detail view.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey there and thank you so much for the quick reply. Im sorry but I am not sure where the line is being put together. I have the PayPal API directory which has several sub directories and a lot of PHP files. I looked thru form.php and dont see where its being created. would it be in dodirectpayment.php? Or should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: hi, yes.it may be in the dodirectpayment.php file. actually all the users having different types of methods and files for calling API. but you should check where the API is being called.

Answer (score 0):

you are suppose to called this function-
`$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('DoDirectPayment', $nvpStr);`

where

```
$nvpStr =   &PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
            "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName".
            "&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=$country&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";
```

Some parameters may diff for your payment process,

so you can try this.
Thanks.